# Find item sequence does not return expected item

Tags: testing, find, common-lisp

I am using Lispworks try to return the the first item from a sequence immediately greater than a give value.

```
RU 7 : 3 > (find 9 '(3 7 9 13 17) :test '>)
3
```

In above codes, i wish to get the integer value that is greater than 9, but it returned the 3, i wish 13 is returned because 13 is value that is immediately greater than 9.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CL-USER 100 > (find 9 '(3 7 9 13 17) :test '<)
13
```

Comment: Thank you; yes, it seems i have to reverse the operator to solve my problem.